# hierarchical clustering with single linkage in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering

I have a pandas dataframe to do hierarchical clustering.

```
    A   B   C
A   0   1   3
B   1   0   2
C   3   2   0
```

The code I tried:

```
z=linkage(df,'single')
dn = dendrogram(z,labels=index)
```

then I got a strange outcome: A&B as a cluster with distance 1.73 (correct should be 1), then A&B&C as a cluster with distance 3.46(correct should be 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default distance used in `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` is the euclidean distance, defined as `d(x,y) = \sqrt(\sum(x_i-y_i))` (you can check it [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L584)). I think the reason why you got confused is because you were taking the average (and computing the root mean squared error).

So in your case `d(A,B) = \sqrt(3) = 1.73`

Then, since your linkage is `single`, the distance between (A,B) and C is the minimum between d(A,C) and d(B,C), which is `d(B,C) = \sqrt(12)`